# How to find a conformal mapping that transfers the first quadrant onto the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find a conformal mapping that transfers the first quadrant
$D_0 = \{(r, \theta) \mid 0 \leq r < \infty\}$ onto the upper half plane
$D_1 = \{w \mid \operatorname{Im}(w) \geq 0\}$ such that $z_0 = \sqrt{2}i$, $z_1 = 0$, $z_2 = 1$ are mapped to $w_0 = 0$, $w_1 = \infty$, $w_2 = -1$ respectively?

This is what I got after using the generic form for conformal mapping. I am not sure where should I plug the numbers z0, z1, z2, w0, w1, w2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a conformal making of the first quadrant onto the upper half plane, and then use the fact that Möbius transformations are 3-transitive on the upper half plane.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand what I should do. Could you please explain it a little more?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Take a conformal making of the first quadrant onto the upper half plane. How to do that? I mean the approach.

Comment: Consider $z = w^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be w = z^2 ?

Comment: I have posted a picture in the question of what I have as a solution. I am pretty confident that it is w = z^2, but I am not sure where I should plug the numbers z0, z1, z2, w0, w1, w2 in the problem. They cannot be completely useless!